# Is there an Android API to Remove Alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have an app which allows the user to set alarms at various times. Currently, it uses AlarmManager plus a BroadcastReceiver and an AlertDialog to alert the user to an alarm going off.

I'd like to see if my app could make use of the built in alarm clock. I know I can schedule alarms like so:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, new Date(alarm.getTime()).getHours());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, new Date(alarm.getTime()).getMinutes());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, alarm.getDescription());
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

but this presents 2 problems:

1. there does not appear to be a way to schedule an alarm for >24 hours into the future
2. the Android built in alarm only allows 10 alarms to be set

As a work around to item 1, I could use AlarmManager to schedule the users alarm to be set within 24 hrs of it's due time. However, this leaves me with item 2 - ideally I need a way to remove my app's alarms from the Android alarm clock after they'd executed (to avoid my app's alarms taking up alarm space) but can't find a away to get a list of alarms and remove one.

Is this possible, or do I need to stick to the manual AlarmManager/AlertDialog approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an alarm within 24 hours you can use the Alarm. If it's further in the future you'll need to add notification to a calendar event. You could also make your very own custom implementation of an alarm manager, it's all about what your trying to achieve which you haven't said anything about at all.